# French Canadian Keyboard Layout } key being swallowed by WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, keyboard

When a TextBox is inside a ListView in WPF, the CA-FR "}" can't be used. This key is on the Right-Alt (or Alt Gr key) + "<". Other other key combinations on Right-Alt work fine. This can be seen with the following XAML code in MainWindow and switching the built in Keyboard settings in Windows to the French Canadian layout:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Grid.Row="0">
        <ListView.Items>
            <TextBox Width="300"></TextBox>
        </ListView.Items>    
    </ListView>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="300"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

There are 2 textboxes here, one inside a ListView and the other outside. When you press "}" outside of ListView, the TextBox updates appropriately, but in the other case, nothing happens.

What I'm looking for is a workaround for this problem, if anyone has one.

I've tested my real code that has the same issue with snoop and found that the ListView was handling the KeyPress event. I understand that ListView would handle Tabs and other keys for navigation, but I'm not sure what's going on here.

I've also found that I can intercept the KeyPress event in the ListView using PreviewKeyDown, if that helps. Any info is appreciated.

Comment: Is your entire app set to french canadian culture at the entry point?

Comment: No. App is set to InvariantCulture to avoid issues with text parsing and number formatting.

Comment: The actual problem seems to be a bug in WPF, which has gotten some feedback here: [https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/7641](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/7641)